# PHP Select first sentence from each part of the divided text and display together

Tags: php, string, sentence

Can someone please add some code and help me complete the assignment ?
I need help selecting first sentence in a group of sentences of five. Then put these first sentences from each group into one paragraph. Then display them together.

I have already completed major part of this complex task: Using PHP I open file, put contents in array, divide the array into sentences, group the sentences in groups of five.

The code is here:

```
//Reading file contents
$text = file_get_contents( 'majmunskikompjuter.txt' ); 
echo $text;


 //Divide the text into sentences
 
$result = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!;:])\s+/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($result);


//Divide the text into equal parts containing 5 sentences each
$input_array = $result;
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 5, true)); 

//Select first sentence from each part of the divided text and display together ???? Need help
```

Comment: If you're looking for help a [mre] will likely get you better feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You could for example omit the last parameter in array_chunk to not keep the keys, and then use array_map returning the first entry of the array returned from array chunk.

Then use implode with a space.

Example using an [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php):

```
$result = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!;:])\s+/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$result = implode(" ", array_map(
    fn($arr) => $arr[0],
    array_chunk($result, 5))
);
```

Comment: Would you mind writing the full code that I may test in live php page ? I tried adding your suggestion but it did not work. Thank you.

Comment: @TBVTranslation Sure, see https://3v4l.org/tl2j2 or with an earlier version of php without an arrow function https://3v4l.org/eTqtr

Comment: Wonderful! Would you mind - I need to add the finishing touch to the script by looping through the articles which are stored in  the column in a MySQL table. I connect to the database using this: 
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT post_title, post_content FROM wp_posts;  ");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
else {echo "DB query successful <br>";}

Comment: Now, what is the code to loop through the fileds in the wp_posts table, then apply your previous code on each article , add the article title and write all the exerpts in one txt file ?

Comment: Is it possible to establish contact ? My company is going to have these types of jobs and I would like to know if you are interested to hear similar job opportunities ?

Answer (score 1):

I would not say this task is a complex one. You only need to realize what sentence makes a sentence. Typically it is some interpunction as you are trying to do with `preg_split`. I am not English native speaker, so I am not sure that `;` or `:` counts as sentence separator in English, but let us say it is. What you can do is to select (by regex) everything from start of the paragraph up to one of those symbols.

This way you only need one regex to match the first sentence:

```php
$text = '...';
$firstSentences = [];

preg_match_all('/^.*?[\.!\?:;](?:\s|$)/m', $text, $firstSentences);
```

Now `$firstSentences` should have your first sentences. A bit of explanation here:

1. `/pattern/m` looks for multiline inputs. Typically paragraphs are divided into many lines. There is one downside of this - if someone writes paragraphs with breaklines (which should not be done ever), this will work at each line separately. It skips empty lines though, therefore those are not problematic.
2. `^.*?` gives anything `.` that is there `*`, but this section is here only once or none `?`.
3. `[\.!\?:;]` A class (character, that might `.`, `!`, `?`, `:` or `;`.
4. `(?:\s|$)` non capturing `?:` group `()` of a white space `\s` or `|` the end `$`.

Hope this will help you for the asignement. I recommend to have some regular expression cheatsheet if you are not working with it every day.

https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Would you mind writing the full code that I may test in live php page ? I tried adding your suggestion but it did not work. Thank you.

Comment: https://onlinephp.io/c/9ca2c Here you have working example. You can just use the static method on your file content. I would even recommend to create another static method inside the class, that would get filename and then call the first static method itself. But that's up to you.

Comment: Also have in mind, that in regex, there is in step 4 the empty string \s - that means that things like user.name will not end the sentence, because it is probably just something inside the sentence that you do not want to be the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Reading file contents
$text = file_get_contents('majmunskikompjuter.txt');

// Divide the text into sentences
$result = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!;:])\s+/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// Divide the text into equal parts containing 5 sentences each
$grouped_sentences = array_chunk($result, 5, true);

// Select first sentence from each part and store them
$first_sentences = array();
foreach ($grouped_sentences as $group) {
    if (!empty($group)) {
        $first_sentence = reset($group); // Get the first sentence
        $first_sentences[] = $first_sentence;
    }
}

// Display the first sentences together in a paragraph
$first_sentences_paragraph = implode(' ', $first_sentences);
echo '<p>' . $first_sentences_paragraph . '</p>';
```